# Getting centroid of closed line in MYSQL

Tags: polygon, line, mysql

I have a table that contains only closed lines (lines where endpoint is the same as startpoint).

I would need to find a centroid for those lines.

How would I be able to achieve it?

It does not need, to be inner centroid, it can also be just an average of all the line nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain the lines are closed, then you should be able to create polygons out of them, thus easily generating centroids.

I'm not a MySQL user, but these docs seem to have examples that will help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html.